# Some unexpected problems using Angular routing with NGINX routing

Tags: angularjs, nginx

I have an Angular SPA using html routing and ng-route, so all the pages are reached with links like:

```
example.com/products
example.com/home
```

I have one route, my blog, which is reached using server routing with NGINX because it is built using Ghost:

```
example.com/blog
```

If anyone goes directly to one of my routes everything works just fine. However once inside my Angular SPA its a different story:

```
/blog
```

goes to my default route, which is to be expected. But even when I use a hard link:

```
<a href="http://example.com/blog">Blog</a>
```

It still routes though my angular SPA about half the time.

I have a fix using:

```
<a href="http://example.com/blog" target="_blank">Blog</a>
```

But I don't really like sending my users to a new page or tab.

Is there anyway to force Angular to user server routing for specific routes?

Answer (score 0):

Angular intercepts all links. you can probably bypass this by making something like an `ng-click` handler and using `$window.location.assign('/blog')`.